# I made a code for dynamically creating new buttons on a homepage from a separate activity but when I click my button it crashes the entire app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a quiz app where if you click the plus button on the homepage it takes you to another page where you can title your quiz. Once you have inputted the title you click the check mark button and it takes you back to the homepage where the new quiz will appear with the user inputted title. This is what I have so far for my second activity page where you create the title for the quiz:

```
package com.example.k_ari

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class Page2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2)

        val button = Button(this@Page2)
        button.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        val message = "New quiz created"
        val toast1= Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0)

        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)

        val btn = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton2)

        btn.setOnClickListener{

            layout.addView(button)

            toast1.show()

            val intent = Intent(this@Page2, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#250A43"
        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:tint="#250A43"
        android:translationX="280dp"
        android:translationY="580dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#250A43"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.56"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rippleColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the second activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/secondlayout"
    tools:context=".Page2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#99141414"
        android:backgroundTint="#180030"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Enter the title:"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#DADADA"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.433"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.112" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="361dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:autofillHints="title"
        android:background="#99141414"
        android:backgroundTint="#180030"
        android:hint="title"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#DADADA"
        android:textColorHint="#9ADCDCDC"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:translationY="170dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:translationY="600dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#180030"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the logcat:

```
2020-12-22 12:13:18.614 24120-24120/? E/Toast: setGravity() shouldn't be called on text toasts, the values won't be used
2020-12-22 12:13:19.631 24120-24120/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.k_ari, PID: 24120
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.k_ari.Page2$onCreate$1.onClick(Page2.kt:30)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8178)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8147)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30233)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8414)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: please add some logcat information

Comment: Use LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT at the place of  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT. Also replace Button(this) with Button(this@Page2)

Comment: Does your linear layout specify `orientation`? If not, this might be the case of crash.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code according to this and check:

1. You have used "this" as reference of click listener rather than of Activity.
2. Button's parent layout is LinearLayout so replace ViewGroup with LinearLayout
3. Get reference of button and toast outside of click listener because it doesn't required to create everytime on click.

Modified Code:

```
val button = Button(this@Page2)
button.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

val Message = "New quiz created"
val toast1= Toast.makeText(applicationContext, Message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0)

val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)

val btn = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton2)

        btn.setOnClickListener{
            
            layout.addView(button)

            toast1.show()

            val intent = Intent(this@Page2, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried to use your code but for some reason it still crashes when i click the button. When i removed layout.addView(button) and keep everything else it works. I'm not sure why its crashing when i use layout.addView(button). Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Put your exception log from Logcat which will be helpful to solve this easily. Also add your XML layout design file.

Comment: Could you please take a look? Thank you!

Comment: So the issue is here val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout), mainlayout is not part of activity_page2 XML layout so it is coming null and you are trying to add a view on null object reference.
You have to make proper activity XML layout reference with it's views only, as you are mixing two XML resource in one only.